# Convert char[] to byte[] without losing 'bits'

Tags: java, android, types, unsigned

I'm developing an Android 2.3.3 application with Java.

This app is an iOS code with unsigned data types port to Java.

On iOS it works with `UInt16` and `UInt8`. In one case instead using `byte[]` I'm using `char[]`.

But know I have to send that `char[]` as a `byte[]` using a [DatagramPacket](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/DatagramPacket.html).

If one element of char[] is 128, how can I do to insert into byte[] and the receiver gets 128. I don't know what happens if I do this:

```
char c = (char)128;
byte b = (byte)c;
```

Which will be `b` value?
128 = 10000000. b = -1 or b = 127?

How can I convert `char[]` to `byte[]` without losing any **bits**?

Comment: `char`s are not bytes.  What about the `☻` character?

Comment: You need to use a Unicode encoding.

Comment: @SLaks: It doesn't *sound* like the OP's `char` data is really characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java `char` is an unsigned 16-bit quantity. So you can directly convert your `uint16` to `char` without doing anything else.

For unsigned 8-bit quantity you have 2 options:

1. Use `byte`. It also holds 8 bits. You don't lose any bits just because it is signed. However, if you do arithmetic with it you need to remember that Java will scale `byte` up automatically to an `int` and sign-extend it. To prevent this just always mask it like this:

   byte b;
   int foo = 5 * (b & 0xFF);
2. Use `char`. It is unsigned and can hold 16 bits so the 8 bits will fit in there quite nicely. To put a `byte` into a `char` just do this:

   byte b;
   char c = (char)(b & 0xFF); // Mask off the low-order 8 bits

To put a `char` into a `byte` just do:

```
char c;
byte b = (byte)c; // Truncates to 8 bits
```

Be aware that `byte` in Java is signed, so that whenever you do arithmetic with it you need to mask the low-order 8 bits only (to prevent sign-extension). Like this:

```
byte b;
int foo = (b & 0xFF);
```

You can do all the normal bitwise operations you want with a byte without having to mask:

```
byte b;
if (b & 0x80) ... // Test a flag
b |= 0x40; // Set a flag
b ^= 0x20; // Flip a flag from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0
b ^= ~0x10; // Clear a flag
byte x = b << 3; // Shift left 3 bits and assign
byte x = b >>> 4; // Shift right 4 bits and assign (WITHOUT sign extension)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the best and more complete answer that I've ever seen before in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to rethink your approach so you don't end up needing to convert `char[]` to `byte[]`.

If your data really is characters, then you want to look at various serialization techniques, such as using [`new String(char[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char%5B%5D%29) to create a string and then using [`getBytes(Charset)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29) to get the bytes as encoded by a given [`Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) (because, of course, the same characters result in different bytes when encoded in ASCII or UTF-8 or UTF-16, etc.).

But from your question, it sounds like you're not really using characters, you're just using `char` as a 16-bit type. If so, doing the conversion isn't difficult, something along these lines:

```
byte[] toBytes(char[] chars) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[chars.length * 2];
    int ci, bi;
    char ch;

    bi = 0;
    for (ci = 0; ci < chars.length; ++ci) {
        ch = chars[ci];
        bytes[bi++] = (byte)((ch & 0xFF00) >> 8);
        bytes[bi++] = (byte)(ch & 0x00FF);
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

Reverse the masks if you want the result to be small-endian instead.

But again, I would look at your overall approach and try to avoid this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I will convert a byte into a char, so with 8 bits I will get 16bits: 1111 1111 = 0000 0000 1111 1111. But I think I could work with java `byte` because I won't lose any bits. And another thing, with those bytes I will use these operations: &, ^, >>, << and +.

Comment: @VansFannel: You've said you want to convert `char[]` to `byte[]`, not `byte` to `char` (which is just: `char c = (char)b;`, but mind how negative values are handled). In Java, `char` is 16-bit data type. `byte` is an 8-bit data type. That's why, above, you see that the resulting `byte` array will need to be twice the number of elements as the original `char` array.

Comment: Ok, but I only need the last 8 bits.

Comment: @VansFannel: Well, that's a trivial modification to the above.